# How to stop Firefox firing mouseleave when DOM node is moved in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am responding to mouseenter events on an SVG path element by making the path the last child in its parent. This is so it appears on top of other elements (no z-index on SVG stuff unfortunately). The problem is that on Firefox this causes a mouseleave event to fire. This works fine on Chrome.

```
// on mousenter
node.parentNode.appendChild(node)
// this triggers a mouseleave .. if i don't move the node it works
```

Does anyone know a workaround or another approach?

Comment: Ugh, that sounds ugly. And I can only think of an ugly workaround: Set a flag to tell your mouseleave handler to ignore it, and clear that flag when you get the event and also after a setTimeout(0), e.g.: `ignore = true; ...append(...); setTimeout(function() { ignore = false; }, 0);` Note the `setTimeout` is *after* the DOM manip that may have queued a call to your event handler (so your handler is earlier in the queue than the `setTimeout` callback).

Comment: Did you tried event.stoppropagation() or event.PreventDefault()

Comment: Yeah, @Robert's solution may well work. If Firefox doesn't see the handler on the handler list, it won't queue the event callback. The only question is *when* it decides to fire the event, whether that decision is synchronous with `appendChild` (it may well be) or made later during rendering.

Comment: @RobertLongson: You know that for this specific situation? (I haven't mucked about with the order of SVG elements, wouldn't be surprised if there were dark corners outside my usual DOM experience.) If you do, that sounds like an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: I worked around the issue with flags and whatnot. Firefox is buggy when it comes to dishing out these mouse events and SVG path elements, especially when the mouse is moved quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the handler before the appendChild and reinstate it afterwards.

Comment: This prevents the mouseleave event from being fired but an additional mouseenter event is still fired. I can workaround the extra mouseenter event.

Comment: Remove both handlers and put them both back if you like then.